# Logged and CheckIn As different user Subversion

Tags: php, linux, svn, ubuntu

Im working on a project that under SVN. i need to logout from svn and logged in as a new user to checkin files to the subversion.

i tried  `$ svn co svn://hostname/myproject myproject --username user_name` no luck

Thanks
Roshan.